# Filter laravel collection in sub collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My collection is like this.

```
Collection {
    0 => Name_Model {
        "id" => 44
        "name" => "The name of "
        "list_angg" => Collection {
            0 => Name_Model_sub {
                "code" => "02"
                "nameofcode" => "The name of 02"
            }
            1 => Name_Model_sub {
                "code" => "01"
                "nameofcode" => "The name of 01"
            }
        }
    }
    1 => Name_Model {
        "id" => 45
        "name" => "The name of thus"
        "list_angg" => Collection {
            0 => Name_Model_sub {
                "code" => "03"
                "nameofcode" => "The name of 3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to filter that model by value of `list_angg->code`. So I try like this. Filter and foreach that `list_angg->code`

```
$jurnals = $filterCollection->filter(function($value, $key) use ($kode_fakultas){
    foreach ($value->list_angg as $lists) {
        $filtered = $lists->where('code', $kode_fakultas);
        return $filtered;
    }
    return $filtered;
});
dd($jurnals);
```

I try use method `reject()` and `map()`.
But filter didn't work as well. Is I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understood the question correctly.

To filter all elements which `list_angg->code` has the given value you can use a combination of `filter()` and `contains()`.

```
$filterCollection->filter(function ($value) use ($code) {
  return $value->list_angg->contains('code', $code);
});
```

- `filter()` returns all values in a collection which return a truthy value.
- `contains()` returns `true` or `false` if a collection contains a value matching the condition provided, which can be a closure, a value or a key and value.

Keep in mind `contains()` uses "loose" comparison, so if you need a strict match you can use `containsStrict`.

Your code is not filtering correctly because in the filter closure you are always returning the model instance, which evaluates to `true` or `false` based on the first element and therefore it is considered as a pass or fail based on that.

References:

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-contains
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-containsstrict

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by first restructuring the collection according to your requirements. For example:

```
public function formatCollection($collection)
 {
  $results = [];
     foreach ($collection as $item)
     {
         $results[] = [
             'foe' => $item['bar'],
             'baz' => $item['foo']
         ];
     }

    return collect($results);
 }
```

This will return the required json format and after that you can apply your filters to it. For Example:

`$result = formatCollection($collection);`

This will return the collection on which you can apply

```
$result->filter(function(value){
  return (value === 'foo');
}
```

This will return the required information or models you require in your collection.